# Delete local contacts on Android, by date when them was downloaded (syncronized) from Google Contacts?

Tags: android, google-contacts-api, android-developer-api

I researched a lot but I could not find a way to delete contacts based on the date them was downloaded from Google Contacts Cloud. The idea is to delete massively contacts that are behind of some specific date. I would like to do it on Android developing an app Android app that should work like a job which runs every specific time.